# Unity 3D Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2021.3.5 (latest), I wrote a script in C# for player movement, Horizontal input (A, D) movement works just fine but vertical input (W, S) is not working.

Code:

[image]

Comment: Please use code blocks when posting code. **Don't** post images of code.

Answer (score 1):

You assigned the same variable name `moveDirection` for both vertical and horizontal directions, do not do that. Instead, assign horizontal input and vertical input to two different variables, say `moveDirectionX` and `moveDirectionY`. Adding both of these vectors gives the result.

```cs
Vector3 moveDirectionX, moveDirectionY;

public void MovePlayer()
{
    moveDirectionX = orientation.forward * verticalInput;
    moveDirectionY = orientation.right * horizontalInput;

    RB.AddForce((moveDirectionX + moveDirectionY).normalized * moveSpeed * 10f, ForceMode.Force);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but all it did was make Vertical input work but now Horizontal input doesn't work

Comment: @DatBoiChonkey, I made a small error (`orienation.forward` instead of `orientation.right`), fixed it, try now

Comment: I'll check if it works

Answer (score 0):

In `Unity window` go to `Edit` -> `Project Settings` -> `Input Manager` -> `Axes` -> `Vertical`.

You can change your input buttons in `Negative Button` and `Positive button` field or you can add alternative input: `Alt Negative Button` and `Alt Positive Button`.

[Input Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSb5b.png)